# Añadir 'or' en comando sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Estoy realizando una búsqueda con el comando `sed`, para sustituir el resultado por otra palabra. Debo de buscar en la columna **Gender** la **F** y sustiturila por **Female**, y la **M** para sustituirla por **Male** (F = Female; M = Male).

**En caso de no encontrar ni la F ni la M, no debe mostrarlo. Y solo esta permitido utilizar un único comando `sed`**

He probado con lo siguiente, y me funciona para encontrar la F y sustiturila:

```
sed 's/F/Female/g' demographic_info.csv
```

Pero no logro que busque también por la M y me la sustituya. Además los valores que son diferentes también me los muestra, **¿Como puedo agregar un `or`, o algo similar?**

Esto es una parte de lo que contiene **demographic_info.csv**:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,O,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
5,F,29,finnish,english 
6,F,23,swedish,finnish english 
7,O,19,swedish,finnish english french 
8,F,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
9,F,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french
10,O,20,finnish,english 
11,F,26,finnish,english swedish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comando sed acepta varias sentencias separadas por `;`, aunque son más bien un AND: borra, sustituye si (condición) y sustituye si (otra condición)

- Borra las líneas con `,O,`
- sustituir F por Female
- sustituir M por Male

```
    $ sed '/,O,/d;s/F/Female/g;s/M/Male/g' test.csv
    user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
    0,Male,19,finnish,english swedish german 
    1,Male,30,urdu,english 
    3,Male,20,finnish,english french swedish 
    4,Female,20,finnish,english swedish 
    5,Female,29,finnish,english 
    6,Female,23,swedish,finnish english 
    8,Female,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
    9,Female,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french
    11,Female,26,finnish,english swedish
```

Comment: Habia probado varias formas menos esta... Muchas gracias. En este caso aun me muestran los que no son F o M (es decir, me muestra los que son valores 'O'), ¿hay alguna forma de excluirlos?

Comment: Qué quieres decir con *excluirlos*?

Comment: Que no se muestren al lanzar el comando. En Gender hay 3 tipos de valores: F, M y O, pues los que sean O que los ignore. Y solo salga en consola los M y F (Male y Female)

Comment: Se puede hacer que se borren esas líneas